# How do I populate arraylist to excel (VSTO) in C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I have a arraylist (array_list) consisting of values, I want to populate this arraylist (array_list) in excel sheet.

Further there are some values in arraylist(array_list) which i will not be populating in excel sheet.
I am going to call the excel sheet from c#, using VSTO.

How do I accomplish the above.

Comment: When you say populate the arraylist in excel, do you mean that you simply want to write the values of the array on a spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, indeed, i want all the values of array list in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is pretty ugly, but it works - write out your arraylist contents into a 2d array, and dump it to the worksheet:

```
var arrayList = new ArrayList();
arrayList.Add("Alpha");
arrayList.Add("Bravo");
arrayList.Add("Charlie");

var excel = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
var worksheet = (Worksheet)excel.ActiveSheet;

var array = new object[1, 3];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
   array[0, i] = arrayList[i];
}

var firstCell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];
var lastCell = worksheet.Cells[1, 3];
var range = worksheet.Range[firstCell, lastCell];
range.Value2 = array;
```

Alternatively, if your list is small enough, you could simply iterate over your array list and write the contents cell by cell:

```
var row = 1;
foreach (var value in arrayList)
{
   var cell = (Range)worksheet.Cells[row, 1];
   cell.Value2 = value;
   row++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I followed your second way, but still uglier than yours, I had the some of the values in array collection has null, and that caused trouble while placing in the cell. Had to iterate each and every single column value.